# flexible selecton of functions to call with different signutres

Tags: python, module

overall structure of the code is:

SETUP_INPUTS

1. maybe input1
2. maybe input2
3. etc

RUN_ANALYSIS

1. maybe compute_metric_foo
2. maybe compute_metric_bar

The issue:
what inputs are setup controlled by config file and depends on the date, so on any given day only some inputs maybe available. Inputs drive what metrics to compute and become arguments to perform the computations.

An idea. Once inputN runs register results with python module.
This way it is easy to see what's available and each comp_metric function can just select what it needs

Pseudo code would look like this:

#results_registry.py

```
RESULTS_REGISTRY = dict()
```

#input1.py

```
import results_registry
def run:
  results_registry['input1'] = _produce_input() #prob. dataframe or class
```

#comp_metric_foo

```
def run():
  is_in1 = 'input1' in results_registry.RESULTS_REGISTRY
  is_in2 = 'input2' in results_registry.RESULTS_REGISTRY  
  if not(is_in1 and is_in2):
    return
 
 in1 = results_registry.RESULTS_REGISTRY['input1']
 in2 = results_registry.RESULTS_REGISTRY['input2']

 do_stuff()
```

#driver script

```
if config['input1'] and some_other_test:
  input1.run()

if config['input2'] and some_other_test:
  input2.run()

comp_metric_foo.run()
comp_metric_bar.run()
```

does this work? better approaches to this, especially considering very different function signatures and invocation timings?

thank you,
sorry if post is too long